# r cbind a single column of a dataframe with another dataframe without changing the column name

Tags: r

suppose I have two data frame:

```
df1 = data.frame(x=1:4,y=2:5)
df2 = data.frame(x2=1:4,y2=2:5)
```

If I cbind df1 and df2, everything is OK

```
> cbind(df2,df1)
x2 y2 x y
1  1  2 1 2
2  2  3 2 3
3  3  4 3 4
4  4  5 4 5
```

if I cbind df2 with the 2nd column of df1, the column name will change:

```
> cbind(df2,df1[,2])
x2 y2 df1[, 2]
1  1  2        2
2  2  3        3
3  3  4        4
4  4  5        5
```

Is there anyway that I can preserve the column name?

Comment: `cbind(df2, df1[2])` also would have worked

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
cbind(df2, df1[,2, drop=FALSE])
```

When you only select one column from a data.frame, R by default will turn it into a vector and vectors don't have "names". By using `drop=FALSE`, it says a data.frame which tracks column names.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an option using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   select(y) %>%
   bind_cols(df2, .)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `cbind(df2,y=df1[,2])`